# How to Display the async/throw functions return value inside the textView?

Tags: swift, function, core-location, cllocation, swift-concurrency

This is the function I am calling, which uses the latitude and longitude, converts them into city name and country name, and then returns city name or country name depending on what I want.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation


struct junoWeatherEntryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var cityVM = allCities()
    @State private var searchTerm = "San Francisco"

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            search
            Spacer()
            ForEach(cityVM.weather){ item in
                Text("\( try await reverseGeocode(lat: item.lat ,lan:item.lan).locality ?? "Unkown")")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reverseGeocode(lat: Double, lan: Double) async throws -> CLPlacemark {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lan) // <- New York

        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
                guard
                    error == nil,
                    let placemark = placemarks?.first
                else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error ?? CLError(.geocodeFoundNoResult))
                    return
                }

                continuation.resume(returning: placemark)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here cityVM is `@Published var weather = [WeatherResponse]()`

Error i am getting is

```
1.Cannot pass function of type '(WeatherResponse) async throws -> Text' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
2.Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(WeatherResponse) async throws -> Text' to non-throwing function type '(Array<WeatherResponse>.Element) -> Text'
```

I want to show the return value in the TextView how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You are in an async context here. Your function cannot return. If you provide more information how this is used we could help you solve this. Else read up concurency with completionhandlers.

Comment: Put the asynchronous geocode stuff into `AllCities`and `@Publish` the result. In a parameter of a SwiftUI view you have no task to run the asynchronous code in and there is no way to handle the error.  And please name structs with starting capital letter according to the naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reverseGeocodeLocation` calls its completion handler asynchronously (i.e., later). So, there are two common patterns:

1. Use traditional completion handler patterns. E.g.:

   ```swift
   func reverseGeocode(lat: Double, lon: Double, completion: @escaping (Result<CLPlacemark, Error>) -> Void) {
       let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
       let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon) // <- New York

       geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
           guard
               error == nil,
               let placemark = placemarks?.first
           else {
               completion(.failure(error ?? CLError(.geocodeFoundNoResult)))
               return
           }

           completion(.success(placemark))
       }
   }
   ```

   And you would call it like so:

   ```swift
   reverseGeocode(lat: 31, lon: 32) { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):     print(error)
       case .success(let placemark): print(placemark.locality ?? "Unknown")
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use modern Swift concurrency, e.g.,

   ```swift
   func reverseGeocode(lat: Double, lon: Double) async throws -> CLPlacemark {
       let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
       let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon) // <- New York

       guard let placemark = try await geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location).first else {
           throw CLError(.geocodeFoundNoResult)
       }

       return placemark
   }
   ```

   And you would call it like so:

   ```swift
   Task {
       var placemark = try await reverseGeocode(lat: 31, lon: 32)
       print(placemark.locality ?? "Unknown")
   }
   ```

Now, in both of those examples, I am returning the entire `CLPlacemark`. You could change these to return the `String` of just `locality` or `county` based upon your `cityName` Boolean, but the basic idea would be the same. Use completion handler or `async` pattern to handle the return of the asynchronously retrieved information.

---

In your revised question, you ask for an example of how to use this in SwiftUI. You could, for example, use [`.task { ... }`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = CityViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(viewModel.results) { result in
                Text(result.name)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            try? await viewModel.search()
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd put the business logic in the view model, not the view:

```swift
@MainActor
class CityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var coordinates = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 31, longitude: 32),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7, longitude: -74),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.05, longitude: -118.25)
    ]

    @Published var results: [CityResult] = []

    private let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    func search() async throws {
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            let placemark = try await reverseGeocode(coordinate)
            results.append(CityResult(name: placemark.locality ?? "Not found"))
        }
    }

    private func reverseGeocode(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) async throws -> CLPlacemark {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        guard let placemark = try await geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location).first else {
            throw CLError(.geocodeFoundNoResult)
        }

        return placemark
    }
}

struct CityResult: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}
```

But don't get lost too in the details here, as your example will undoubtedly vary. The idea is to use `.task` to start the asynchronous task, which can update some observable property.

Comment: I have a small question about how to capture the function's result in computed property so that I can store it in a struct . I tried this but I keep getting the error "async" call in a function that does not support concurrency." I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You should not wrap something slow (or asynchronous) inside a computed property.

Comment: so how do i display function's returned value on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the question according to my doubt

Comment: See revised example showing how you might do it. Your question was missing some details, so I filled in a few gaps with mock objects of my own design. But don't get lost in the implementation details, but rather just understand the broader pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the clearest examples on this subject. I've been pulling my hair out using the other form of reverseGeocodeLocation.  Your example #2 works exactly like I want it to without treating it as a Task. I'm using it in a command line utility and I want to wait for it's completion before doing other work.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you had a helpful assistant who knows how to take a location and return a city name to you, but it takes him a while to do it.

Now you are a very busy person, so you are going to do some work up to the point that you need to identify a location.  You write down the information on a piece of paper and you hand it to your assistant.  He hops on a bike to find the answer while you get back to work.  You work until he returns and hands you the answer.

That's what your function is doing.  It runs up to the point that you call `geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation` then it sends the location off to another processing thread that will look up the information.  The current thread keeps running without waiting for an answer.  It runs the `if(city name)` block at the same time the other thread is doing its work.

When that other thread is done, `geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation` calls your `completionHandler` code with the result.

This is a fundamental idea of concurrency and your question suggests it caught you by surprise.  You may need to do some background reading on Asynchronous coding for Apple systems.